# Which python lib for plotting 3D particles

Tags: python

I am new to python and one of my assignments I am doing is asking to, "Write a program that puts identical non-overlapping particles of diameter d in a cubic (3d) lattice with periodic boundary conditions. The linear length is L. Write the program in such a way that you can vary the number of particles. Demonstrate that your program works and show at least one visualization"

I am looking to see what 3D lib I should use, any suggestions?

Also, any suggestions on how I should approach this problem? I'd imagine i can randomly generate the x,y,z coordiantes of the n number of particles I have the user input. How can I ensure they do not overlap though? I am also confused on the "periodic boundary conditions" but thats not python related :|

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: Ensuring they don't overlap is probably ridiculously simple in comparison to the rest of the work.

Comment: I would go for matplotlib. IIRC it can handle pretty well 3D things.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib works fine for simple 3D plots and is very popular so it's easy to find documentation, tutorials and help. However, for something specifically geared to 3D plots, try [Mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/).